# Create DLL in Visual Studio c++ that will be loading in VB

Tags: visual-studio, dll

**Description**

I am trying to create a project that will create a DLL file (.COM managed DLL) using VS2010. This DLL will be loaded in VB. Also, I will be using STL in my dll.

**Already Tried**

1 -  Created Visual C++ -> win32 -> Win32 project -> Next -> selected DLL -> ticked export Symbols -> Finish. Will this be a managed .COM DLL? How do I check? Will this DLL be working on 64-bit operating system as 64 bit dll or as x86 dll?

2 -  Created Visual C++ -> MFC-> MFC DLL -> Regular DLL using shared MFC DLL
Will this be a managed .COM DLL? How do I check? Will this DLL be working on 64-bit operating system as 64 bit dll or as x86 dll?

Also, There are other two options Regular DLL With MFC statically linked and MFC extension DLL. I don't prefer the first one because it makes it harder to upgrade my dll in the future, And I don't know what the second one does?

Are there any other options I can use to create DLL?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ".COM managed DLL"? STL is native C++, so it's not clear what you're after. Maybe instead of asking how to create a DLL, you should describe the problem and ask how to solve it.

Comment: I am beginner with DLL stuff. By ".COM Managed DLL", I meant a DLL that is created using Visual c++ (Managed/Un-managed?) and can be loaded by VB (Managed). This DLL will use STL (Vector and Map) internally. This DLL has some events. The application that loads this DLL can subscribe to these events. So, to subscribe to an event, the dll needs to be registered (regsrv32.exe is used to register COM components). I added the word ".COM" just for the event subscription. If there is a better way to do, can you share it with me?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should eliminate the requirement to use STL and COM and just create a managed assembly. A managed assembly can be consumed by managed code and can publish events for use by managed code. In Visual Studio, this would be a CLR -> Class Library project.

If you must use STL and COM alongside managed code, then you'll need to create a mixed mode DLL. That's not simple to do, and I don't recommend that route if you have limited experience.

Alternatively, if you can eliminate the requirement for managed code, then you can create a native-only DLL that implements COM interfaces. COM interfaces can be consumed by native or managed code, but they require registration before use and a managed wrapper for use from managed code.

Comment: Thank you Owen. I can avoid using STL. However, how can you register the managed assembly without using COM? Can you share some tutorial? one Final question: Why "CLR-> Class Library Project" and not ATL-> ATL project and select COM+ support?

Comment: You don't register managed assemblies (however you can install them in the Global Assembly Cache, or GAC), you just reference the assembly directly from the code that consumes it. ATL projects are native C++ code.